# Third-order polynomial (i.e., system) - comparing coefficients

Tags: polynomials, control-theory, linear-control

I have a third-order polynomial (i.e., characteristic equation) for a proportional controller. In attempting to find the ultimate (or critical) gain, $K_c$, this is compared with a generic equation. My polynomial, I guess, is arbitrary but here is it anyway:
$$ s^3+4s^2+4s+4K_{C} $$
The coefficients are compared directly to the expansion of this equation:
$$(s^2+\omega^2)(s+a)$$

My questions are specifically: where does this generic form [i.e., $(s^2+\omega^2)(s+a)$] come from and why does this work?

Comment: Trying to think this through logically, it is clear that the ultimate gain produces an oscillatory response of constant amplitude. Therefore, at this point one would expect 2 of the 3 roots of the characteristic equation to lie on the imaginary axis. So, following this logic I would imagine that this 'generic' equation is representative of this case. Although I cannot see how? That's assuming my reasoning here is correct.

Comment: Looking again, I think I'm starting to see the light! From the $s^2$ term this will give us 2 poles (i.e., solutions) at $s = +-j\omega$?

Comment: Since the coefficients of $s$ and $s^2$ are equal in your polynomial, the factorization $(s^2+\omega^2)(s+a)$ is only possible if $\omega^2=a\,$. If you are only interested that the two have the same roots, then that will be the case when the polynomial has two complex roots $z, \bar z\,$ (they must be conjugate), so that $(s-z)(s-\bar z)=s^2-|z|^2$ and you can choose $\omega = j |z|\,$.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks. If for instance the coefficient of $s$ was, for example 6, then the previous factorization would stand. I see. Thanks